# Error 1350: SharePoint online Call error： getListItems (Exception): The server sent HTTP status code 429: null

Tags: sharepoint-online, status

We are getting below error, when we execute SharePoint Online Query Operation.

> The server sent HTTP status code 429: null

This error occurs only on Japanese Server Credentials. The problem occurs till 19 o'clock (Japanese Time).  After 19 o'clock it does not reproduce at all.

The other server is in Israel, where the problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get throttled in SharePoint Online.

When a user exceeds usage limits, SharePoint Online throttles any further requests from that user account for a short period. All user actions are throttled while the throttle is in effect.

Check the article: [Avoid getting throttled or blocked in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)